# How to select option in bootstrap-select dropdown from db value

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is my Bootstrap dropdown html:

```
<label>Gender</label>
  <select name="gender" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $gender; ?>">
     <option>Male</option>
     <option>Female</option>
  </select>
```

I am new to both bootstrap and php. I tried to echo $gender as a value in the html select. I would like to have the option selected based on the value of $gender. For example, if $gender = "Male" then Male should be selected on the form. Likewise, if $gender="Female" then Female should be selected. The variable $gender has the correct values but I need to understand how I can pass that value into the select as the selected option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just compare with option value and set `selected` attribute

```
<label>Gender</label>
<select name="gender" class="form-control">
 <option value="Male" <?php echo $gender == "Male" ? "selected" : "" ?>>Male</option>
 <option value="Female" <?php echo $gender == "Female" ? "selected" : "" ?>>Female</option>
</select>
```

Notice : The value select tag gets from its selected option value

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`selected`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#Examples) property with the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary),

**PHP**

```
$selected = $gender === 'Male' ? 'selected' : '';
```

**HTML**

```
<option [...] <?= $selected ?>>Male</option>
```